# SQL Column naming

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I would like to ask if which of this 2 is better? The use of colName AS Name or Name = colName.  How are they differ and which of the 2 is more convenient and faster way or any of the 2 has difference in terms of memory usage or etc.?

Thank you and god speed!

Comment: Have you read [this blog](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for the reference... This is a very big help for me for more understanding on SQL.

Comment: I don't think this is a big performance concern, but you want to choose one over the other if you are worried about being able to easily port your database code from SQL Server to another RDBMS.

Comment: I always use "AS" when I rename columns. I used "=" for query conditions.  The time of execution and result produces the same. Maybe use the function on what you are comfortable with.

Comment: @GNMercado we have the same thought as well.  I think thats the best way to set everything in a standard coding.  Thank you for your help both of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I always use "AS" when I rename columns. I used "=" for query conditions. The time of execution and result produces the same. Maybe use the function on what you are comfortable with.